# Image and mask normalization in semantic segmentation for cancer

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, keras, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

Could someone please help me, in semantic segmentation tasks, should the image and mask be normalized in the batch generator class or only one of them should be normalized?

I'm using the following code to normalize image and mask:

```
  mean_val, std_val = img.mean(), img.std()
  img = (img - mean_val)/std_val
```

for example :

here image and corresponding masks are normalized for the prostate cancer segmentation task

[image: normalized image and mask]

while here only the masks are normalized

[image: Only mask is normalized]
which one is the correct practice?

```
 def __getitem__(self,i):
    
            index= self.indexes[i * self.batch_size : (i + 1) * self.batch_size]
            
            X = np.empty((self.batch_size,  self.crop_dim[0], self.crop_dim[1],3)).astype(np.uint8)
            
            Y = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.crop_dim[0], self.crop_dim[1],5)).astype(np.uint8)
            for i,ID in  enumerate(index):

                dim= (self.crop_dim[0],self.crop_dim[1])
                img=cv2.imread(self.img_list[ID],cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  
                img = cv2.resize(img,dim)
                
                mask=imageio.imread(self.labels[ID],as_gray=False, pilmode="RGB")
                mask = cv2.resize(mask,dim)
                mask= create_labels(mask)
               
                # Augement training patches only
                if self.augmentation:
                    
                    sample = self.augmentation(image=img_numpy, mask=mask_numpy)
                    img_numpy, mask_numpy = sample['image'], sample['mask']


                 mean_val, std_val = img.mean(), img.std()
                 img = (img - mean_val)/std_val

                 mean_val_mask, std_val_mask = mask.mean(), mask.std()
                 mask= (mask - mean_val_mask)/std_val_mask


                X[i,]=img_numpy
                Y[i,]=mask_numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

## No!

You do not want to normalize the labels - you want to predict them directly, you do not want the target (per pixel) to change based on the global statistics of the mask.

**Why normalizing?**
It is common practice to normalize the inputs to a DNN model. This is motivated by the desire to control the "dynamic range" of the activations at different layers. This, in turn, helps the optimization process to converge in a more rapid and stable manner.
You can find an in-depth analysis of this normalization in this excellent paper:
*He, K., Zhang, X., Ren, S. and Sun, J.*, [**Delving deep into rectifiers: Surpassing human-level performance on imagenet classification**](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_iccv_2015/html/He_Delving_Deep_into_ICCV_2015_paper.html) (ICCV 2015).

This rationale does **not** apply to the labels.